# On Checkbox click show hide div having same class dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want click on the check box and hide the respective content.

Now in my code all the content with same class gets hidden when I click any one of the checkbox.

```
Since my front end tags are in apex I do not want to use id, attr, name,value. I want to use class and fix this issue, exactly in the way I have written in this fiddle.
```

Fiddle link for reference

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {

    $('.div1').hide();
  } else {
    $('.div1').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<h3 align="center"> This JavaScript shows how to hide divisions </h3>
<form>
  <input type="checkbox">Exam1
  <div class="div1">I am content1!
  </div>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox">Exam2
  <div class="div1">I am content2!
  </div>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox">Exam3
  <div class="div1">I am content3!
  </div>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox">Exam4
  <div class="div1">I am content4!
  </div>
  <br>
</form>
```

```
https://jsfiddle.net/6ybp2tL6/
```

Is this possible??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/6ybp2tL6/3/)

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
  ($(this).is(":checked")) ? $(this).next().hide() : $(this).next().show();
});
```

Comment: This worked for me had to navigate to parent of my div and apply this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to hide all the divs with class `div1` initially,

```
 $(".div1").hide();
 $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
     $(this).next('.div1').toggle(!this.checked); //toggle(false) will hide the element
 });
```

And toggle the visibility of the relevant div element with class `div1` by using `next()` and `toggle()`

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6ybp2tL6/4/)